# How to retrieve data from the Google Datastore?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, google-cloud-datastore

I use java servlets. I wrote a code which has no error,But it returns me an empty list always.
I dint want to update Datastore from the servlet. i just want to read entities. i'll enclose my code tell me where is the problem.

I always get the data store is empty.This is just a test code.Even this dosent seem to work. searched internet for week . All for vain.

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    resp.getWriter().println("Hello, world");

    DatastoreService datastoreService = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    resp.getWriter().println(datastoreService.getIndexes());


    if (datastoreService.getIndexes().isEmpty())
        resp.getWriter().println("the data store is empty");


    Query query = new Query("IMAGES");
    PreparedQuery pq = datastoreService.prepare(query);


    for (Entity entity :pq.asIterable())

    {
        resp.getWriter().println(entity.getKind() );
        resp.getWriter().println(entity.getAppId() );

        resp.getWriter().println(entity.getKey() );
    }

    if (!pq.asIterable().iterator().hasNext())
        resp.getWriter().println("the data store is empty");



}
```

Comment: Is this deployed or are you running in devserver?  Also, if you go in your google admin tool, can you see entities in your datastore viewer?

Comment: yes its deployed. I deployed it for learning purpose. I did add entities in my Datastore using developer console. When the query evaluates it returns empty always .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rectified my problem . I forgot to add a namespace. here is a snippet on How to set namespace in GAE DataStore.

```
// Set the namepace temporarily to "abc"
String oldNamespace = NamespaceManager.get();
NamespaceManager.set("abc");
try {
  ... perform operation using current namespace ...
} finally {
  NamespaceManager.set(oldNamespace);
}
```